# what's the purpose of “--cache-builds” in carthage?

Tags: ios, swift, carthage

As titled, what's the purpose of "--cache-builds" in carthage command line? if missing this, what could happen and what's the benefit to have this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [docs](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage):

**Caching builds**

By default Carthage will rebuild a dependency regardless of whether it's the same resolved version as before. Passing the `--cache-builds` will cause carthage to avoid rebuilding a dependency if it can. See information on version files for details on how Carthage performs this caching.

**Note:** At this time `--cache-builds` is incompatible with `--use-submodules`. Using both will result in working copy and committed changes to your submodule dependency not being correctly rebuilt.

Comment: "Passing the --cache-builds will cause carthage to avoid rebuilding a dependency if it can." 

This doesn't indicate under what conditions "it can." For example, does the option cache the actual frameworks that were generated, or does it only cache metadata about the build?